# How to call the multiple REST services in parallel at a time?

Tags: java

I want to call multiple REST services from the REST client how can
I call them as single thread used for each call. I wan to call them in parallel

Comment: ```java.util.concurrent.Future``` is your friend

Comment: Do read our [what topics are allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guides. As it is currently written, it is Off topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for giving insight on this

Answer (score 3):

The below is the sample code for multiple database request that i made for my purpose

```
   CompletableFuture<Company> companyCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return  Company.find.where().eq("id", id).findUnique();  
        });

        CompletableFuture<List<Domain>> domainsCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return Domain.find.where().eq("company_id", id).findList();
        });

       // wait for all the data
        CompletableFuture allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(companyCompletableFuture, domainsCompletableFuture);

allDoneFuture.get(); // wait for all done
company = companyCompletableFuture.get();
domain = domainsCompletableFuture.get()
```

what you need to changes it to make http request to make able for your porpose.

Comment: Thanks Md for giving the detail information with code this is really helpful